# I am trying to learn a simple flask program, but while exporting the app (using the command $ set FLASK_APP=hello) I am getting an error

Tags: python, cmd, set, virtualenv

I am trying to make a simple flask program, but while exporting the application (using the command $ set FLASK_APP=hello) I am getting the error " 'set' is not recognized as an internal or external command, openable program or batch file " Here is my terminal:

```
c:\Program Files\Python38-32>myproject\Scripts\activate
(myproject) c:\Program Files\Python38-32>set FLASK_APP=hello
'set' is not recognized as an internal or external command, openable program or batch file.
(myproject) c:\Program Files\Python38-32>
```

I have searched in many websites but cannot find the solution. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try calling it *before* `myproject\Scripts\activate`. It looks like after that `activate`, you're in a different shell than CMD (IIRC, `set` is not a program, but a command of CMD).

Answer (score 2):

You are using Windows.  Windows does not use the "export" command to set environment variables.  Instead, you need:

```
set FLASH_APP=hello
```

Comment: Thank you but I am getting the same error with 'set'.